# Run geth looking for peers forever on AWS

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am new on blockchain.. sorry for asking very basic question:

I am running my first geth private node on AWS using ubuntu using this command:

```
geth --datadir ~/ethdata/ --networkid 12345 --verbosity 3 --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr ec2-3-238-204-220.compute-1.amazonaws.com console 2 >> ~/ethdata/eth.log
```

My code is running for ages. Is there something I should do?

> INFO [04-08|12:15:48.358] Looking for peers
> peercount=0 tried=99  static=0 ERROR[04-08|12:15:58.263] Snapshot
> extension registration failed   peer=89027a8b err="peer connected on
> snap without compatible eth support"

Comment: Why is your network id 12345?

Comment: Note sure ,that what I have seen the code being used and I have used . Do you know what I suppose to use
geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --networkid 45634 --verbosity 3 --
ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr <Public
DNS address of your Node 1> console 2>> ~/eth-dev/eth.log

Even using this also I am getting the same error

Comment: Do you want to run your own node for the Ethereum blockchain (the real thing) or a private blockchain that only you uses?

Comment: I am learning private blockchain leveraging Ethereum .

Comment: How many nodes are you running? You need more than one otherwise a node alone will not have peers.

Comment: By the way, what does `Snapshot extension registration failed` mean? I haven't found anything on that error online.

Comment: have you solved this problem? I am experiencing the same situation when connecting to a node. ```
ERROR[07-24|09:06:59.321] Snapshot extension registration failed peer=cb5b9771 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
```